# Javascript : Problem while passing parameter to a function

Tags: javascript, function

I am passing a parameter to a javascript function from jsp.

```
  <a href="javascript:void(0)" title="Update" 
   onclick="fnUpdate(<s:property value='roleTypeUid'/>);">
```

Now the roleTypeUid is a String with space in between (eg. System Admin) . So it is not working . If I replace the attribute with a no-space string , it gets passed fine.

Am I missing something ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" 
   title="Update" 
   onclick="fnUpdate('<s:property value='roleTypeUid'/>');">
```

Comment: I get this error  Error: illegal character
Source File: localhost:8080/searchRole
Line: 1, Column: 9
Source Code:
fnUpdate(\

Comment: @vinoth You may need to escape them.

Comment: @vinoth, how about `onclick="fnUpdate('<s:property value='roleTypeUid'/>');"`?

Comment: Is roleTypeUid meant to be a string or an included variable? Did Darin forget to escape it?

Answer (score 1):

The called function within `onclick` has to be a string, you can't reference variables directly in it.

```
onclick="fnUpdate(\"<s:property value='roleTypeUid'/>\");"
```

That string is evalled onclick and thus becomes a function. That's why it may be better to add handlers [unobtrusive](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript)